# Loop multiply int to lower int

Tags: c#, for-loop, multiplication

I've got the following loop:

```
    public int multiply(int Z)
    {
        //Z=5
       for (int i = 1; i <= Z; i++)
        {
             int Y=Z*i;
             return Y;
           //i wanna Y multiply x*4*3*2*1 all loops in one result
        }
        return Z;
    }
```

What I'd like to know how to do is:

Create a new multiply int Y =Z*4*3*2*1 
Result of multiply would be In Console Write Line:

```
("value for your loop is " +test.multiply(5));
value for your loop is 120
```

Can this be done by a `for` loop or am I wrong?

Comment: Please Don't Write Uppercase The First Character Of Your All Words In Your Question.

Comment: I'm not clear on what it is you're trying to do. Are you calculating a factorial?

Comment: BTW, factorials get big **really** fast; even with a return value of `long` (rather than `int`), don't expect to get very high...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you actually mean is that you want to calculate the factorial of Z.

```
public int Factorial(int Z)
{
    if (Z < 0) then return 0;

    int res = 1;
    for (int Y = 1; Y <= Z; Y++)
    {
        res *= Y;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is called [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial):

```
public int Factorial(int num)
{
    int factorial = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {
        factorial *= i;
    }

    return factorial;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/LB3Ts8)

You can also get factorial recursively (this is basic exercise):

```
public int Factorial(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1)
        return 1;

    return num * Factorial(num - 1);
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/x9QIKJ)

Comment: This certainly is a factorial, but I'm not sure if the OP is asking this (their formula suggests Y=Z*4*3*2*1) and Z is the value passed - but it might be a question that needs clarification!

Comment: @Charleh you might be right but since OP was passing 5 and output was 120, I assume it's factorial.

Comment: @DaRkS If this answer solved your problem you need to mark it as accepted (tick on the left-hand side from answer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
public int multiply(int Z)
{
    int Y = Z;

    for (int i = Z; i > 0; i--)
    {
         Y *= i;
    }

    return Y;
}
```

Comment: Obviously this is assuming you want to multiply Z by the values - your question states (Z*4*3*2*1) as an example so I made this assumption. For a factorial Leri's answer is the one!

Comment: You probably want to initialise `Y = 1`, else you're doing `Z * Z` at the start (instead of `Z * (Z-1)`).

Answer (score 1):

Factorial using lambdas:

```
Func<int, int> factorial = null;
factorial = x => x <= 1 ? 1 : x * factorial(x-1);
var result = factorial(10);
```

:-)

Comment: Fortunately, for large numbers it'll probably numeric-overflow before the stack-overflow ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell, not a big deal, I can change it to BigInteger :=)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int multiply(int Z)
{
    int result = Z;
    for (int i = 1; i <= Z; i++)
    {
        int Z*=i;
    }
    return Z;
}
```

Comment: Add an explanation, please. You answer was marked as low quality by an automatic process and is on the way to be deleted.